# Looking for suggestions on how to structure an app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need to make an app that has the following:

- UINavigationController as a base. I'll need to drill down and push and pop other screens.
- I need to be able to swap the bottom screen on the stack. The user should be able to (using a menu of some sorts) select different options which will alternate the first screen on the stack. From there they can drill down and push further screens on and pop them off accordingly.

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

I've tried using a single view controller as the rootViewController which manages the interchanging of other view controller but run into a couple of issues down the road with that. I can't help but think there's a more "proper" way to achieve this.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need, noting that index 0 is your rootViewController and substituting whichever viewController you'd want to change in the second line:

```
NSArray * viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSArray * newViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[viewControllers     objectAtIndex:0], [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1], thirdController,nil];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers];
```

Comment: NOTE:  There is another version of that method (setViewControllers) that takes a BOOL for "animated" which may be handy for you...

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have done it but introduced a new issue as well. Anything I have in the NavBar is wiped out. Left and right buttons, custom button title, all gone.

Comment: Where are they being created?

Comment: All created in the Nav Controller's init.

Comment: I should mention that viewControllers is of count 1 in my case. According to the class reference "the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array". Weird.